# Icons in angular project not visible on the browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, node-modules

I have been working on an angular project which worked fine. But now the images are not displayed on the browser when I run ng serve.It says 404 error. Except for the images the rest seems to work fine. I did not change any code. The angular icon on the tab of the browser(favicon) is not visible too.

Updating node-modules and reinstalling angular didn't work either.The image file and the path is correct though I get the 404 error.

```
 http://localhost:4200/assets/img/single_user.png 404 (Not Found)

    Image (async)       

push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setAttribute    @   platform-browser.js:1087
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugRenderer2.setAttribute @   core.js:11462
createElement   @   core.js:8134
createViewNodes @   core.js:10360
createEmbeddedView  @   core.js:10307
callWithDebugContext    @   core.js:11344
debugCreateEmbeddedView @   core.js:10845
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.TemplateRef_.createEmbeddedView @   core.js:8894
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView    @   core.js:8760
push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/common.js.NgIf._updateView    @   common.js:3375
set @   common.js:3343
updateProp  @   core.js:9449
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline   @   core.js:9200
checkAndUpdateNodeInline    @   core.js:10507
checkAndUpdateNode  @   core.js:10469
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @   core.js:11102
debugCheckDirectivesFn  @   core.js:11062
(anonymous) @   LoginComponent.html:1
debugUpdateDirectives   @   core.js:11054
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:10451
callViewAction  @   core.js:10692
execComponentViewsAction    @   core.js:10634
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:10457
callViewAction  @   core.js:10692
execEmbeddedViewsAction @   core.js:10655
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:10452
callViewAction  @   core.js:10692
execComponentViewsAction    @   core.js:10634
checkAndUpdateView  @   core.js:10457
callWithDebugContext    @   core.js:11344
debugCheckAndUpdateView @   core.js:11022
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges  @   core.js:8838
(anonymous) @   core.js:4571
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @   core.js:4571
(anonymous) @   core.js:4462
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:391
onInvoke    @   core.js:3820
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke    @   zone.js:390
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run   @   zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run  @   core.js:3734
next    @   core.js:4462
schedulerFn @   core.js:3551
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub   @   Subscriber.js:195
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:133
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next  @   Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next   @   Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @   Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit   @   core.js:3535
checkStable @   core.js:3789
onHasTask   @   core.js:3833
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask   @   zone.js:443
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount  @   zone.js:463
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount  @   zone.js:291
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask   @   zone.js:212
drainMicroTaskQueue @   zone.js:601
Promise.then (async)        
scheduleMicroTask   @   zone.js:584
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:413
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask  @   zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @   zone.js:258
scheduleResolveOrReject @   zone.js:879
ZoneAwarePromise.then   @   zone.js:1012
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @   core.js:4345
./src/main.ts   @   main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:78
0   @   user.ts:6
__webpack_require__ @   bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules    @   bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback    @   bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @   main.js:1
```

Comment: Where are you deploying app?

Comment: i think you are new to development, i assume after running ng serve you are not able to fetch image

Comment: The project worked fine and the image was displayed too. But after I closed the project and started working back, the image was not displayed in the browser

Comment: how are you running project?

Comment: ng serve using cmd

Comment: share the error log and update your question with proper code attachment ,have you moved your project folder to other location?

Comment: updated the code. Did not change the location but renamed the project

Answer (score 0):

Rename your `project name` to `name` set at the time of application creation.
Else certain changes need to be done in `angular.json` and `package.json`

Comment: There is no official command to rename the project ,you need to manually search and update each place where project name is used and set it to new one which is very hectic and not advisable,if the answer helped you solve your problem in some way or other please mark it correct.